# Why this.store.select("uiState") return an empty object in ngrx/store (2.0+)

Tags: angular, redux, rxjs, ngrx

I have this code in my effect/store:

```
  @Effect() newMessages$ = Observable.interval(5000)
        .withLatestFrom(this.store.select("uiState"))
        .map(([unreadMessages, uiState]) => new NewMessagesReceivedAction({
          unreadMessages,
          currentThreadId: uiState.currentThreadId,
          currentUserId: uiState.currentUserId
        }))
```

Webstorm warns me that:

> Property 'currentThreadId' does not exist on type '{}'.

And here is my store file:

```
     export interface ApplicationState {
      uiState: UiState,
      storeData: StoreData
    }

    export const INITIAL_APPLICATION_STATE: ApplicationState = {
      uiState: INITIAL_UI_STATE,
      storeData: INITIAL_STORE_DATA
    }
```

And here is my uistate file:

```
    export interface UiState {
          userId: string;
          currentThreadId: string;
        }

        export const INITIAL_UI_STATE: UiState = {
          userId: undefined,
          currentThreadId: undefined
        }
```

Anyone know why?

UPDATE:

After @cartant suggestion I updated the code of the @Effect() as below, and I ran into another Webstorm Typescirpt error:

```
      @Effect() newMessages$ = Observable.interval(5000)
        .withLatestFrom(this.store.select<UiState>("uiState"))
        .map(([any,uiState]) => uiState)
        .filter(uiState => uiState.userId) //Error right here --- As I need to filter out the uiState.userId when there is no userId when the store initialized with undefined value. 
        .switchMap(uiState => this.threadsService.loadNewMessagesForUser(uiState.userId))
        .withLatestFrom(this.store.select<UiState>("uiState"))
        .map(([unreadMessages, uiState]) => new NewMessagesReceivedAction({
          unreadMessages,
          currentThreadId: uiState.currentThreadId,
          currentUserId: uiState.userId
        }))
```

> Argument of type '(uiState: UiState) => string' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: UiState, index: number) => boolean'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.)

I need a way to filter out the initial state or any empty userId situation to make sure I do not pass in undefined or null into Firebase call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies with this bit of code:

```
this.store.select("uiState")
```

The `select` operator extracts the named property from the store's state and emits its value. However, TypeScript has no way of inferring the type of that property. To solve the problem you can specify the type explicitly via the [type variable](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html):

```
this.store.select<UiState>("uiState")
```

Regarding this line in your amended question:

```
.filter(uiState => uiState.userId)
```

The [`filter` operator](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-filter) takes a predicate that is supposed to return a `boolean` and you are returning `userId`, which is a `string`. There is no implicit TypeScript conversion, so you need to be explicit:

```
.filter(uiState => Boolean(uiState.userId))
```

Comment: Use your code this.store.select<UiState>("uiState"), I still run into typescript error. Not sure why (typescript noob as well). Please see my updated question. Thanks again!

Comment: `userId` is a `string`, and `filter` wants a `boolean` result, so you need to be explicit `.filter(uiState => Boolean(uiState.userId))`

Comment: so is the filter code should be like this: .filter(uiState => { if(uiState.userId) {return true; } else {return false}})  ? I saw people wrote .filter(uiState => !!uiState.userId) - is it the same thing - If userId is NOT empty, continue. Else break operation?

Comment: It's all the same.

Comment: When asking questions on SO, I think it's a good idea to look at it from another reader's perspective. Instead of updating and adding to the question, you might want to consider asking a new, separate question. The `filter`-related parts of the amended question and answer are not reflected in the title. A separate question might have been more useful to other readers.

Comment: Agree! Will do next time. Thank you tho for all your answers.